# Can VM on Azure use some service that azure provide

Tags: c#, azure, cloud

I want to use a kind of database that is not provided by the Azure. However there are other services of Azure like Blobs, Cache and Notification Hubs that I would like to use. I'm a bit confused about:

1. Can you do it? If so, then how?
2. Is it possible to set up the environment for developing so I am able to test these services?

My program will be an Asp.net web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer to your question is Yes, you can do that.

For the database which is not provided by Azure, you can make use of Azure Virtual Machines and install the database software there. Please note that since you're installing the software on an Azure Virtual Machine, you would be responsible for maintaining that software like upgrading, applying patches, backups etc.

For other services, again the answer is yes. You can simply start using these services. For example, if you want to use blob service you would start by creating a storage account and then start using blob service.

Regarding setting up development environment, Azure provides a SDK which includes a compute emulator and storage emulator using which you can test your application. There is no emulator for Notification Hubs so you would have to do the testing by using the service in Azure only.